# How to interpolate within an interpolation?

Tags: javascript

I have a constant called `CLASSES`:

```
const CLASSES = {
    root: "root",
    vertical: "master",
    horizontal: "alternate",
}
```

I have a variable `gridType` which has a value of either a string of `vertical` or `horizontal`.

```
render() {
    const { gridType } = this;  // equals either a string of 'vertica'l or horizontal 


    return html `<div class="${CLASSES.root}"</div>`;
}
```

How would I add `gridType` class to the returned html? I can't do `<div class="${CLASSES.root} ${CLASSES.gridType}"</div>` since `gridType` is not a value on `CLASSES`

Comment: Interpolate `style` and not `gridType`

Comment: `style` is just a legacy leftover? Why do you use the `window.style` globally?

Comment: FYI `calc(100%/3)` should be `calc(100% / 3)`

Comment: oops leftover, yes!  will remove.  I had it like that but want to put the styles in my SASS file instead

Comment: OK, where do you use now `gridType` in your code exactly? Have you tried to `console.log( gridType )`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use bracket-notation:

```
<div class="${CLASSES.root} ${CLASSES[gridType]}"</div>
```

Comment: How is `CLASSES[gridType]` any different than doing `CLASSES.gridType`? And he already stated that "I can't do `<div class="${CLASSES.root} ${CLASSES.gridType}"</div>` since `gridType` is not a value on `CLASSES`"

Comment: `gridType` is a dynamic value of either `horizontal` or `vertical`, the right way to access the values in `CLASSES` is using `bracket-notation`.

Comment: Ah I see that now